# How to style Java FX TableView column header using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, columnheader

I am rather new to JavaFX and CSS styling (and also stackoverflow). I am wondering how can one style the table header of the column.
This is what my header looks like currently:
[Current styling of my table view column header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRhSH.jpg)

This is what I want it to look like:
[Styling I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxkWs.jpg)

I have tried applying the following css styling without avail:

```
.table-view .column-header .nested-column-header
{
    -fx-background-color: #AAAAAA;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2, 0.5, 1, 1);
}

.table-view .column-header
{
    -fx-background-color: #AAAAAA;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2, 0.5, 1, 1);
}

.table-view .column-header .filter
{
    -fx-background-color: #AAAAAA;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2, 0.5, 1, 1);
}
```

I also checked out the caspian.css file found in the jfxrt.jar but that could not point me in the right direction.

So if anyone has any ideas, it would be great. :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend to try something with the following style classes:

```
.table-view .column-header-background
```

I changed my column header background with this css and it worked:

```
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Are you sure that you dont have a treetable? Because the styling class is named `tree-table-view` instead of `table-view`.